# Errors in using SSOAP

Tags: r, soap

I'm using `SSOAP` to use the WoRMS SOAP API (http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=webservice) in a package I maintain `taxize` - all functions that use this API start with `worms_*()`. If you want to install the package, instructions here (use install from github option): https://github.com/ropensci/taxize#install-taxize. All `worms_*()` functions work fine on my OSX 10.7 machine, but users on Linux and Windows machines report problems. For example, a number of users report this error when calling some functions, e.g.: `get_wormsid(searchterm = "Baetis pygmaeus")`

```
Error in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE) : 
  no slot of name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"
```

I've seen this error reported in other packages on SO, but seems no solution specifically given for this error. Curious why this error only results on some OS's and not on others. It seems this error is specific to `S4` objects, which `SSOAP` uses.